# How to transform multiple files with in sub-directories using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

For example, there are chapter1 and chapter2 sub-folders inside parent folder, named:"S9ml". In both sub-directories:Chapter1 and Chapter2 has many .htmls. I want to transform all these .html' to remove white-spacing or Strip-white spacing. How do I do it? Please do help on how to run using Oxygen Editor?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" />

<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()">
   <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried this but in config transform, when I select the ${cfdu} getting, your access is denied.

Comment: Do you want to run the same XSLT separately against all documents in those directories? Or do you want one XSLT to process and e.g. merge all documents in a single run? And HTML documents as the input to XSLT, are you sure these are well-formed XHTML to be parseable with an XML parser? And if you use oXygen and want to use that with the help of oXygen, why is there no tag for that tool?

Comment: Correct. Same script against all the .html files living in those sub-directories. Basically, I must remove spaces using <xsl:strip-space> on all the files of .html. As a single input,  I am able to do it, but not sure on how to strip-space among thousands of .html's inside the sub-directories. Or using normalize-space(), I must remove unwanted spaces among all the files.

Comment: For oXygen, see https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/25.0/ug-editor/topics/apply-batch-transformation.html.

Comment: Thanks but its not clear. I just want an example where we normalize all the files in a sub-directories using XSLT. Also, for input what do we give in the transformation-scenario. Generally, I worked on giving single input as html file consisting tables and transform many using result-document. My requirement now is to normalize multiple files in a sub-directories. Please provide me some directions. Thanks.

Comment: ask the oXygen support if you really can't work it out from their documentation. That documentation of the batch transformation describes it.